# How to prove that $|\tan z| \lt 2$ on the contour $x=\pm~ \pi n, y=\pm~ \pi n$?

Tags: complex-analysis

We are in the complex plane. And I just cannot prove that  $|\tan z| \lt 2$ on the contour $x=\pm ~\pi n, y=\pm ~\pi n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write

$$\tan(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}$$

So that:

$$|\tan(x+iy)|=\frac{|e^{ix}e^{-y}-e^{-ix}e^{y}|}{|e^{ix}e^{-y}+e^{-ix}e^{y}|}$$

As to what to do explicitly:

On the vertical sides, (since $e^{\pm in\pi}=(-1)^n)$:
$$|\tan(\pm n\pi+iy)|=\frac{|e^{-y}-e^{y}|}{|e^{-y}+e^{y}|}=|\tanh(y)|< 1$$

and on the right hand side:

$$|\tan(x+in\pi)|=\frac{|e^{ix}e^{-n\pi}-e^{-ix}e^{n\pi}|}{|e^{ix}e^{-n\pi}+e^{-ix}e^{n\pi}|} \leq \frac{|e^{-n\pi}+e^{n\pi}|}{|e^{-n\pi}-e^{n\pi}|}=|\coth(n\pi)|<1$$

Where the bound on the left hand side is estimated similarly.